# Automatically create variables in the __init__ method in a class object

Tags: class, variables, object, automation, initialization

I am new to python and wish to create something like this:

```
class Patch(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.P1 = dict()
        self.P2 = dict()
        self.P3 = dict()
        self.P4 = dict()
```

Since, I have just started working with python I have a manageable set of variables P1, P2, P3 and P4 for instance. Once I get the whole model to work properly I will have something like P1-P100. I was wondering if there is a way to automate this process of generating the variables?

Thanks for your help in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe have a look at [settattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) to accomplish this. Something along the lines of:

```
for i in range(100):
  setattr(self,"P"+str(i),"some value")
```

inside your `__init__`...

But why not just have ONE list, as an attribute in your class, that you populate?